# Need to update "orderby" column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table `test`

```
+----+--+------+--+--+----------+--+--------------+
| ID |  | Name |  |  | orderby  |  | processgroup |
+----+--+------+--+--+----------+--+--------------+
|  1 |  | ABC  |  |  |       10 |  |            1 |
| 10 |  | DEF  |  |  |       12 |  |            1 |
| 15 |  | LMN  |  |  |        1 |  |            1 |
| 44 |  | JKL  |  |  |        4 |  |            1 |
| 42 |  | XYZ  |  |  |        3 |  |            2 |
+----+--+------+--+--+----------+--+--------------+
```

I want to update the `orderby` column in the sequence, I am expecting output like

```
+----+--+------+--+--+----------+--+--------------+
| ID |  | Name |  |  | orderby  |  | processgroup |
+----+--+------+--+--+----------+--+--------------+
|  1 |  | ABC  |  |  |        1 |  |            1 |
| 10 |  | DEF  |  |  |        2 |  |            1 |
| 15 |  | LMN  |  |  |        3 |  |            1 |
| 44 |  | JKL  |  |  |        4 |  |            1 |
| 42 |  | XYZ  |  |  |        5 |  |            1 |
+----+--+------+--+--+----------+--+--------------+
```

Logic behind this is when we have `procesgroup` as 1, `orderby` column should update as 1,2,3,4 and when `procesgroup` is 2 then update `orderby` as 5.

Comment: Couldn't get what you mean. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ydoow its ok I got the answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This might help you

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY processgroup, ID ) AS SNO, ID FROM TABLE1
)
UPDATE TABLE1 SET TABLE1.orderby= CTE.SNO FROM CTE WHERE TABLE1.ID = CTE.ID
```

Comment: Thanks. So I came to know I understood correctly. @RedDevil